# Dual NIC's, Dual VLANs, Dual Gateways

Tags: networking

I've scoured the Forums and found some threads 'close' to what I'm trying to do but none of the suggestions have worked for me.  Here's an overview of what I'm trying to do:

*Two NICs installed on a VM of Server 16.04

*NICs are name ens32 and ens34

*ens32 is the first NIC and works fine

*ens34 won't get DHCP (other servers using this same vnic do (VMWARE)) but does accept a static IP.

*I'm able to pass data over ens32 but not ens34.  ifup ens34 gives common errors of "not configured" etc but adding it to /run/network/ifstate seems to cure that.

*I've added metric 0 and 1 but no luck.

I'm feeling like there is something I need to do on the route but have been unable to find a correct answer.  On Windows, this config simply works so I assume I must do a bit more manual configs.  I'm using the 172 subnet for AP management and 10.71 as the DHCP subnet.  Each goes through a separate gateway.
`ifconfig` shows both NICs up with IPs:

```
ens32     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:9a:37:6a
          inet addr:172.16.210.2  Bcast:172.16.211.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe9a:376a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:32252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:29971051 (29.9 MB)  TX bytes:1458237 (1.4 MB)

ens34     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:a3:43:5b
          inet addr:10.71.0.2  Bcast:10.71.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:93 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:20016 (20.0 KB)

/etc/network/interfaces:
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens32
iface ens32 inet static
        address 172.16.210.2
        netmask 255.255.254.0
        network 172.16.210.0
        broadcast 172.16.211.255
        metric 0
        gateway 172.16.210.1
        dns-nameservers 172.16.2.101 172.16.2.102
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed


auto ens34
iface ens34 inet static
        address 10.71.0.2
        netmask 255.255.240.0
        network 10.71.0.0
        broadcast 10.71.15.255
        metric 1
        gateway 10.71.0.1
```

Comment: And what you wish to accomplish? Currently, in your output `ens34` is configured with `static` param and because of that will not ask `dhcp` for `ip`. What say command `route -n`?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Sorry, I pasted the configs after I changed from DHCP to Static but the affect is the same.  No traffic will pass over ens34.  Here is route -n:
'Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.210.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens32
0.0.0.0         10.71.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 ens34
10.71.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 ens34
172.16.208.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 ens32'

Comment: I feel like an idiot on this forum.  Can't even get my code to post right.

Comment: Currently, based on output, your default route is on `ens32`. `ens34` at this moment you can use only to access network. maybe is better to say host on network `10.71.0.0/255.255.240.0`. What you wish to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah, I see that too but that won't work for this design.  What I'm trying to do is have this Ubuntu server serve two VLANs on two gateways.  A wireless controller is installed for access points with multiple VLANs, spanning two networks.  An access point needs to see the controller on VLAN210 with IP of 172.16.210.2 so it can acquire a "management IP" on a secured production network.  That AP then needs to serve internet to wireless users on an unsecured Guest VLAN (10.71.0.0/20).  This is easy from my Cisco, VMware & Windows gear but I'm stumped on Linux networking.

Comment: network dia will be heplful ... If you need from `ubuntu server ` only acces to `172.16.210.2` you do not need to have Gateway on that card. Remove it, and try is topology working.

Comment: It all makes sense now.  Thank you for your time.  The issue was never on the Linux Server but at the ESX Host server.  Security policies were preventing traffic over that VLAN despite it working on the Windows Server.  The difference?  The Windows server I tested on was not joined to the domain so had no security restrictions over VMWARE.  Other Windows machines on the domain as well as the Linux server were blocking that VLAN(201).  -now that I know the issue, applying the fix should be pretty simple.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help